# PHP: Stop class execution without terminating the script (Or includes)

Tags: php, class

In the class below, I need kill() to end whatever is going on within the class and just stop all and any processes WITHIN the class, not the script:

```
<?php
class email {
    //Expressions
    const exp_name      = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    const exp_email     = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    const error         = "We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.<br/>";
    private $msg        = 'Thank you for subscribing';
    protected $status   = true;


    function __construct() {
        self::validate();
        echo '<br/>the CLASS continued</b><br/>';
    }


    private function validate() {
        //Empty fields
        foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
            $val = str_replace( ' ', '', $value );
            if ( $val === '' ) {
                self::error( 'empty', $key );
                self::kill(); //If empty, this should end the loop and class
            } //if:empty
        } //foreach


        //Validate Name
        if( !preg_match(self::exp_name,$_POST['Name']) ) {
            self::error( 'name' );
            self::kill(); //kill


        //Validate e-Mail
        if( !preg_match(self::exp_email,$_POST['e-Mail']) ) {
            self::error( 'email' );
            self::kill(); //kill
        }
  }


    public function status() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function msg() {
        return $this->msg;
    }


    private function error( $type = null, $value = null ) {
        switch( $type ) {
            case 'empty':
            $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The following field is empty: </b>" . $value . "</div>";
            self::set( false );
            break;

            case 'name':
            $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</b></div>";
            self::set( false );
            break;

            case 'email':
            $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The e-Mail you entered does not appear to be valid.</b></div>";
            self::set( false );
            break;

            default:
            self::set( false );
            $this->msg = self::error;
        }
    return; //kill app
    }


    private function set( $boolean = false ) {
        $this->status = $boolean;
    }


    private function kill() {
        //die();
        //exit( $this );
        //exit();
        //return;
        //break;
    }
}


$email = new email();
echo $email->msg();
echo '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';
echo 'The script continued!!!';
?>
```

Comment: Not possible. PHP is single-threaded. Killing its one thread kills everything. You could try returning back up the call stack until you're "outside" the object, though I'm not sure exactly how you could trigger such a 'deep' return.

Comment: I will need examples, since I am not an expert.

Comment: `throw new Exception('My Message')` Use try/catch outside of the class to handle the exception. [Exceptions in the manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: @datasage for what I read, a good way would be to modify the method error() to throw exceptions and kill() to catch them?

Comment: Generally speaking, if a class generates exceptions, you shouldn't be trying to catch them in the same class.

Comment: PS. `return` DOES NOT WORK!!! It only stops the current class' running method, or "step" level withing a method.

Answer (score 12):

As answered above in a comment, try to use "try" and "catch" blocks.

Change the "validate" method

```
private function valdidate( $type = null, $value = null ) {
    // Anything that is going wrong:
    throw new Exception("Your error message");
}
```

Outside the class:

```
try {
      $mail = new email();
} catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); // Handle the message properly here.
}
```

For more info about exception see:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `self::kill();` simply use `return;`

If you need `kill` to do other stuff then simply use `return self::kill();` whenever you need to call it and change `kill` to:

```
private function kill() {
    doStuff();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No one stop you to just return boolean on `validate` method, then setup a simple if/else block to evaluate its result.

```
private function validate() {
    //Empty fields
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
        $val = str_replace( ' ', '', $value );
        if ( $val === '' ) {
            // You shouldn't call staticaly 
            // self::error( 'empty', $key );
            $this->error('empty', $key);
            // self::kill(); //If empty, this should end the loop and class
            return false;
        } //if:empty
    } //foreach


    //Validate Name
    if( !preg_match(self::exp_name,$_POST['Name']) ) {
        $this->error( 'name' );
        return false;
    }

    //Validate e-Mail
    if( !preg_match(self::exp_email,$_POST['e-Mail']) ) {
        $this->error( 'email' );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then in the constructor :

```
if ($this->validate()) {
    echo '<br/>the CLASS continued</b><br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly Instead `kill()` could use `return false`. As far as I know return would 'throw' you outside of the method, and the execution will not be affected in no way.Sorry if I didn't understand your problem correctly.

Best Regards!

Comment: What I want is...when the class email uses kill(), to ONLY completely stop ITSELF from continue running (To "kill" the class email) and allow the [php] scrip to continue running. In this example, `echo $email->msg();
echo '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';
echo 'The script continued!!!';`

Comment: Yes I have got the idea, as far as I know you should remove the method `kill();` and replace it with `return` it will exit the method. as an alternative you could return false and with a conditional statement to compare the returned result like:
`if (self::validate() !== false) { //do something }` this solves your problem(at least in theory that is)

Comment: Yeaaa...however, the objective still remains, to stop just the class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no 'kill me' option in a class. PHP uses the [unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) method to destroy a variable, and that cannot be called from within a class. As the manual states 'It is not possible to unset $this inside an object method since PHP 5.', so you cannot kill your class.

That being said, how would you go about it then to make sure nothing happens when it doesnt validate? Make sure you check the status in each method of the class that shouldnt continue on error. Below you will find your code altered to show this process. Be sure to read the comments as to why I did something.

```
<?php
class email {
    //Expressions
    const exp_name      = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    const exp_email     = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    const error         = "We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.<br/>";
    private $msg        = 'Thank you for subscribing';
    protected $status   = true;


    function __construct() {
        //first check if it validates.
        //if it doesnt, end the constructor so the "class continued" line won't show.
        if (!self::validate()) {
            return;
        }


        echo '<br/>the CLASS continued</b><br/>';
    }


    private function validate() {
        //have the validate method return true/false.
        //Now you can use the output of this method to stop the script if needed

        //Empty fields
        foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
            $val = str_replace( ' ', '', $value );
            if ( $val === '' ) {
                self::error( 'empty', $key );
                return false; //just return false when it doesnt validate
            } //if:empty
        } //foreach


        //Validate Name
        if( !preg_match(self::exp_name,$_POST['Name']) ) {
            self::error( 'name' );
            return false; //just return false when it doesnt validate
        }

        //Validate e-Mail
        if( !preg_match(self::exp_email,$_POST['e-Mail']) ) {
            self::error( 'email' );
            return false; //just return false when it doesnt validate
        }

        //else return true
        return true;
    }

    public function status() {
        //always allow the script to return the status
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function msg() { 
        //always allow the script to return the error message
        return $this->msg;
    }

    //example function on how to make sure nothing happens on error
    public function send() {    
        //return false on error so the rest method is not executed
        if ($this->status!==true)
            return false;

        //else continue
        echo "I'm sending an email!";
        //mail(.....)
    }


    private function error( $type = null, $value = null ) {     
        //you set the status to false here, so you can use it to check if an error occured
        //since you always set it to false, remove it from the switch statement. 
        //This way there is less duplicate code and thus less chance for errors

        self::set( false );

        switch( $type ) {
            case 'empty':
                $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The following field is empty: </b>" . $value . "</div>";
                break;

            case 'name':
                $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</b></div>";
                break;

            case 'email':
                $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The e-Mail you entered does not appear to be valid.</b></div>";
                break;

            default:
                $this->msg = self::error;
        }

        return;
    }


    private function set( $boolean = false ) {
        //use a check to set the value to make sure its always a boolean
        //this way it will be false unless you actually set it to true.
        $this->status = ($boolean===true);
    }
}


$email = new email();

//now you can do a check for the message and only continue if there was no error
if ($email->status() !== false) {
    //Do whatever you want with the e-mail
    $email->send();
    echo 'An e-mail has been sent!';
} else {
    echo 'Something was wrong with the email ('.$email->msg().')';
}

//or another approach could be to directly send it and catch if there was an error
//make sure to check for false with === to be sure its realy a boolean. 
//If you would just check with == the method would also fail if the send() method would return 0 for instance
if ($email->send() === false) {
    echo 'Something was wrong with the email ('.$email->msg().')';
}

//but no matter what, the script will continue
echo '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';
echo 'And the script continued!!!';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it programatically like this:

```
class email {
    //Expressions
    public static $errorOccuredInCurrentRun = false;

    const exp_name = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    const exp_email = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    const error = "We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.<br/>";

    private $msg = 'Thank you for subscribing';
    protected $status = true;

    public static function factory(){
        //du your validation
        self::$errorOccuredInCurrentRun = false;
        self::validate();
        if(!self::$errorOccuredInCurrentRun){
            return new Email();
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    private function __construct() {
        echo '<br/>the CLASS continued</b><br/>';
    }

    private static function validate() {
        //Empty fields
        foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
            if(self::$errorOccuredInCurrentRun){
                break;
            }
            $val = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
            if ($val === '') {
                self::error('empty', $key);
                self::kill(); //If empty, this should end the loop and class
            } //if:empty
        } //foreach
        //Validate Name
        if(self::$errorOccuredInCurrentRun){
            if (!preg_match(self::exp_name, $_POST['Name'])) {
                self::error('name');
                self::kill(); //kill
                //Validate e-Mail
                if(self::$errorOccuredInCurrentRun){
                    if (!preg_match(self::exp_email, $_POST['e-Mail'])) {
                        self::error('email');
                        self::kill(); //kill
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function status() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function msg() {
        return $this->msg;
    }

    private function error($type = null, $value = null) {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'empty':
                $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The following field is empty: </b>" . $value . "</div>";
                self::set(false);
                break;

            case 'name':
                $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</b></div>";
                self::set(false);
                break;

            case 'email':
                $this->msg = self::error . "<div class='error'><b>The e-Mail you entered does not appear to be valid.</b></div>";
                self::set(false);
                break;

            default:
                self::set(false);
                $this->msg = self::error;
        }
        return; //kill app
    }

    private function set($boolean = false) {
        $this->status = $boolean;
    }

    private function kill() {
        self::$validationRunCompleted;
    }

}
```

and then use it like that:

```
$email = email::factory();
if(is_null($email)){
    //something went wrong
}else{
    //validation was fine
}
```

i only execute stuff if the current "run" didn't have any errors. And only if there were no errors you get the email object itself with what you can go on and do what you need